# Wordpress Functionality: Custom Theme or Plugin?

Tags: wordpress

I am new to Wordpress (using roughly 6 months) and just now getting into development when I decided I would attempt to replicate a project I have going currently and after reading multiple blogs regarding plugin development and custom post types, I am thoroughly confused as to which direction I should go.  I am in need of creating a site that has back-end management (admin only) and then end-user management where the end-user should have a page that allows them to manage their items.

With custom post types, I am able to create the objects that I will need to use but that doesn't give me total control when it comes to allowing the end-user to modify them from a front-end interface.

With a plugin, I *think* I am able to create exactly what I need but not sure how to yet but at the same time, thinking through the structure of Wordpress, everything is basically a post, correct?  So, if that's the case, my plugin would need to have the ability to register new custom post types.  Does it sound like I am on the right track or am I way off here?

Comment: Try http://wordpress.stackexchange.com

Comment: Oh!  Thanks so much!  I never knew this existed.  I'll take a peek over there and see if this is answered.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Custom Post Types can add a lot of power, especially if you dress up the Custom Fields with meta boxes. You can always use a role-scoping plugin to limit the access of end-users to only be able to use these Custom Posts and nothing else. CPT are a great way to handle inventory management and not rely on a plugin that will either cost $ or potentially break months down the road.

That said, many plugin you would find would most likely just create a Custom Post Type anyway. Take a look around on the codex for info on creating CPT, and if you're interested, look at jaredatch's work on Github.

http://codex.wordpress.org/Post_Types

https://github.com/jaredatch/Custom-Metaboxes-and-Fields-for-WordPress

Comment: Thank you so much for the opinion.  It's exactly what I was looking for.  After looking at example plugins such as CollabPress, it does exactly what you mention, it creates CTPs and meta boxes but they are hidden.  So, this is the route I will take.  Thanks again!